# When to use evaluate new records vs evaluate all records use case in Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Could anyone explain when should we go with evaluate new records vs evaluate all records through a use case.
Its bit difficult to understand the statement given in journey builder setup .
So if anybody can explain with a scenario , that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say that you want to create an order confirmation journey that sends out a series of emails after an order has been confirmed. For this, you have set up a data extension with a status field (pending or approved) and an email address. The journey is recurring and scheduled to run every day. You have also set up an automation that fetches events from your order system and updates the entry data extension accordingly.

If the automation is configured to **update the record** status from ‘pending’ to ‘confirmed,’ you need to **evaluate all records** to determine if the status has changed from ‘pending’ to ‘confirmed.’

On the other hand, if you only **add new records**: one record with when the order is created with status ‘pending’ and another record with order is 'confirmed,’ you only need to **evaluate the new records**. Using this option typically results in faster, more efficient processing.

Docs: Choose How to Process Entry Source Data:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5